# Show commit ID, longer Date and the line number in Git blame

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

I would like reduce the output of git blame to commit ID, date change and the line number.

I tried to get the commit ID, author name and the line number, but my main goal is to remove the author name from the line,

I find it difficult because the author may have many words in his name,(2-3 space separated) so couldn't sed them out. I am new to awk and sed.

```
 git blame --date=short <filename> | sed -e 's, [^(]*, ,' -e 's, [^ ]*\( *[0-9]*)\), \1,'
```

With this I was able to show the commit ID ,author name and line with code.

But  I Want the output to be

```
Commit ID    Date Timestamp   Line number
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the timestamp, just use the `-s` flag :

> Suppress the author name and timestamp from the output.

([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt--s))

Alternatively, `-e` would output the author email instead of the name, it's easier to parse out since there are no spaces.

Comment: I need the commit ID, timestamp and the line number.
I just want to suppress the author name